# Rearrange javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

How do I rearrange the data in the mentioned format.I have to just reformat the array and make the new one:

```
[
   {
      "cost":"1.3947648891000006",
      "start_date":"2020-06-10",
      "account":"1"
   },
   {
      "cost":"1.4069091170999999",
      "start_date":"2020-06-11",
      "account":"1"
   },
   {
      "cost":"1.401164025099997",
      "start_date":"2020-06-11",
      "account":"2"
   },
   {
      "cost":"2.50928182113",
      "start_date":"2020-06-12",
      "account":"2"
   }
]
```

to:

```
[
   {
      "start_date":"2020-06-10",
      "account_1_cost":"1.3947648891000006"
   },
   {
      "start_date":"2020-06-11",
      "account_1_cost":"1.4069091170999999",
      "account_2_cost":"1.401164025099997"
   },
   {
      "start_date":"2020-06-12",
      "account_2_cost":"2.50928182113"
   }
]
```

I have tried the reduce function and map function to no avail.

Comment: So you want to arrange those accounts by `start_date`? Why not having a dictionary with dates as keys, instead of an array, then? I.e. - `{'2020-06-10' : (...), '2020-06-11': (...)}`

Comment: Destructure your array objects into an array of new objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use array.reduce

```js
const arr = 
  [ { cost: '1.3947648891000006', start_date: '2020-06-10', account: '1' } 
  , { cost: '1.4069091170999999', start_date: '2020-06-11', account: '1' } 
  , { cost: '1.401164025099997',  start_date: '2020-06-11', account: '2' } 
  , { cost: '2.50928182113',      start_date: '2020-06-12', account: '2' } 
  ] 

const res = 
  arr.reduce((acc,{cost, start_date, account})=>
    {
    let el = acc.find(x=>x.start_date===start_date)
    if (!el) acc.push(el = { start_date })
    el[`account_${account}_cost`] = cost
    return acc
    },[])

console.log( res )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach to achieve the desired output.
Simply create a dictionary of `start_date` and keep adding `account_i_cost` to the dictionary with a received date. Finally, get all values of the dictionary.

```js
var arr = [{"cost":"1.3947648891000006","start_date":"2020-06-10","account":"1"},{"cost":"1.4069091170999999","start_date":"2020-06-11","account":"1"},{"cost":"1.401164025099997","start_date":"2020-06-11","account":"2"},{"cost":"2.50928182113","start_date":"2020-06-12","account":"2"}];

let objMap={}
arr.forEach(obj=>{
let field=`account_${obj.account}_cost`
objMap[obj.start_date]=objMap[obj.start_date]?{...objMap[obj.start_date],[field]:obj.cost}:{
      "start_date":obj.start_date,
      [field]:obj.cost
   }
})

let result=Object.values(objMap)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a 2-step process, starting by grouping by `start_date` using `reduce` and then by mapping that back to an array:

```js
var input = [{"cost":"1.3947648891000006","start_date":"2020-06-10","account":"1"},{"cost":"1.4069091170999999","start_date":"2020-06-11","account":"1"},{"cost":"1.401164025099997","start_date":"2020-06-11","account":"2"},{"cost":"2.50928182113","start_date":"2020-06-12","account":"2"}];

var grouped = input.reduce( (acc,i) => {
   if(acc.hasOwnProperty(i.start_date))
      acc[i.start_date].push(i);
    else
       acc[i.start_date] = [i];
    return acc;
},{});

var result = Object.entries(grouped).map( entry => {
   var [key,value] = entry;
   var obj = {start_date:key};
   for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++)
       obj[`account_${value[i].account}_cost`] = value[i].cost;
    return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct tool in this case is [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

> The **`reduce()`** method executes a **reducer** function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

---

See the comments:

```js
var account_data = [
   {
      "cost":"1.3947648891000006",
      "start_date":"2020-06-10",
      "account":"1"
   },
   {
      "cost":"1.4069091170999999",
      "start_date":"2020-06-11",
      "account":"1"
   },
   {
      "cost":"1.401164025099997",
      "start_date":"2020-06-11",
      "account":"2"
   },
   {
      "cost":"2.50928182113",
      "start_date":"2020-06-12",
      "account":"2"
   }
];

var refactored = account_data.reduce(function(new_object, current_item){

  // Get the essential information from the current item
  let {start_date, cost} = current_item;
  let cost_key = `account_${current_item.account}_cost`;
  
  // If there isn't a key for this date, create it
  if(!new_object[start_date]){
    new_object[start_date] = {start_date};
  }
  
  // Add the relevant info for the current date
  new_object[start_date][cost_key] = cost;
  return new_object;
}, {});

// Flatten it into an array
refactored = Object.values(refactored);

console.log(refactored);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would **STRONGLY** suggest to not expect an array, and instead have a dictionary with dates as keys.

Then this code:

```
// list = (...)
list.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (!prev.hasOwnProperty(curr.start_date)) {
    prev[curr.start_date] = {};
  }
  prev[curr.start_date][`account_${curr.account}_cost`] = curr.cost;
  return prev;
}, {})
```

will give you this result:

```
{
  "2020-06-10":{
    "account_1_cost":"1.3947648891000006"
  },
  "2020-06-11":{
    "account_1_cost":"1.4069091170999999",
    "account_2_cost":"1.401164025099997"
  },
  "2020-06-12":{
    "account_2_cost":"2.50928182113"
  }
}
```

But if you really want it your way - try this:

```
list.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  let elemWithDate = prev.find(el => el['start_date'] === curr['start_date']);
  if (!elemWithDate) {
    prev.push({'start_date': curr['start_date']});
    elemWithDate = prev[prev.length - 1];
  }
  elemWithDate[`account_${curr.account}_cost`] = curr.cost;
  return prev;
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Go with foreach over the array and look if there is in a hashmap an entry for the date of this object. If so than just add to the corresponding element (via index from the hash) of the result array the new property account_x_cost. Otherwise create a new entry for this object in the resultarray and add the date as index to the hash.

```js
let arr = [ 
    { "cost": "1.3947648891000006", "start_date": "2020-06-10", "account": "1" }, 
    { "cost": "1.4069091170999999", "start_date": "2020-06-11", "account": "1" }, 
    { "cost": "1.401164025099997", "start_date": "2020-06-11", "account": "2" }, 
    { "cost": "2.50928182113", "start_date": "2020-06-12", "account": "2" }
];

let result = [];
let hash = [];

arr.forEach(obj => {
let index = hash.indexOf(obj.start_date);
    if (index==-1) {
        result.push({start_date: obj.start_date, ['account' + obj.account + '_cost']: obj.cost});
        hash.push(obj.start_date);
    } else {
        result[index]['account' + obj.account + '_cost'] = obj.cost;
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is not what this guy wants. Check his results - he has 3 items, not 4